# my input don´t get mark as touched anymore when using onBlur event on my input: redux-form

Tags: reactjs

i am using redux-form on a react project and try to add some custom class on my input depending on its state. the problem is that when i use the onBlur event, my input doesn´t get mark as touched anymore and i cannot display the error. i then get back false for this.props.hasError although the input was blured.
I would really be gratefull if someone could help me. Thanks

```
class FormInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            focusState:  false,
            blurState: false
        }
        this.inputFocus = this.inputFocus.bind(this);
        this.renderTheBorder = this.renderTheBorder.bind(this);
        this.inputBlur = this.inputBlur.bind(this)
    }

    inputFocus() {
        this.setState({
            focusState: true,
            blurState: false
        })
    }

    inputBlur() {
        return this.setState({
            focusState: false,
            blurState: true
        }
    }

    renderTheBorder() {
        if (!this.state.focusState && !this.state.blurState)  {
            return <div className={`input__state `}></div>
        }
        else if ( this.state.focusState && !this.state.blurState ){
            return <div className={`input__state state__focus `}></div>
        }
        else if (!this.state.focusState && this.state.blurState) {
            return <div className={`input__state state__leaveRigth `}></div>
        }
    }

    render () {
        const {url, className, type, placeholder, inputStyle } = this.props;
        const {input, error, hasError } = this.props;

        console.log('hasError: ', hasError)
        return (
            <div className={className} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }} >
                <input type={type} 
                    className={inputStyle} 
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    {...input} 
                    onFocus={this.inputFocus}
                    onBlur={this.inputBlur} />
                    <div className="initial__state">
                        {this.renderTheBorder()}
                    </div>
                { hasError ? 
                   (<div className ="feeback"> {error} </div>) : 
                   (<div className ="space"></div>)  
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

// here is where i render the input component and   use redux-form

```
class SignupForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderInputField({input, 
        meta: {touched, error, active},
        placeholder, type, url} ) {

        const hasError = touched && !active && error !== "undefined";

        return (
            <FormInput className="login__form_input form__icons"
                inputStyle="login__input"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                type={type}
                url={url}
                input={input}
                hasError={hasError}
                error={error} />
        );
}

    render () {

        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <div style={{paddingTop: 1.5 + 'rem', paddingBottom: 1.5 + 'rem'}}>

                <Field name="first"
                    component={this.renderInputField}
                    placeholder="First name"
                    type="text"
                    url={User}
                    validate={[reqFirstName, valFirstName]} />    
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a `console.log` in `inputBlur()` so that you can verify that it actually runs the method when the field is blurred.  That's a good place to start.

Comment: i have already put a console.log(), i always get false for hasError props although because i does not mark the input as touched